# How to format a JSON DateTime into 12 hour time in jQuery

Tags: jquery, json

If I have a JSON DateTime:

```
"DateCreated":"\/Date(1301692095627)\/"
```

How can I format that into a 12 hour time using jQuery?

Right now I'm using this:

```
function DateDeserialize(dateStr) {
    return eval('new' + dateStr.replace(/\//g, ' '));
}
```

Which outputs the JSON object as:

```
Fri Apr 01 2011 17:08:15 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)
```

But I would like to get just the time, in 12 hour format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `.getHours()` method on the date object (which returns 0-23). Check to see if it's over 12 hours, if so, subtract 12 hours otherwise it's already fine.

see this jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/s2hyL/1/

```
var hrs = new Date().getHours();

var hrs12 = hrs > 12 ? hrs - 12 : hrs;
```

If you need to perform formatting (or complex parsing), I highly recommend the [date.js](http://www.javascripttoolbox.com/lib/date/) library by Matt Kruse.

Comment: do you mean take this: "DateCreated":"\/Date(1301692095627)\/" and call the function you wrote on that? or do you mean after I've called DateDeserialize on the object?

Comment: assuming your DateDeserialize method returns a javascript date object, then you would perform the `.getHours()` and transforms on that date object.

Answer (score 1):

```
function DateDeserialize(dateStr) {
    return eval('new ' + item.When.replace(/\//g, ' ')).format("M/d/yyyy h:mm tt");
}
```